# How to use external (from another package) exception filter Nest.js?

Tags: node.js, typescript, rest, nestjs, backend

I'm trying to create shared-module for microservices.

There are two packages:

- @name/hub - ordinary HTTP-service
- @name/lib - shared library

Library contains simple exception-filter module:

1. http.exception-filter.ts

```
import { ArgumentsHost, Catch, ExceptionFilter, HttpException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

@Catch(HttpException)
export class HttpExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
    const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();
    const status = exception.getStatus();

    response.status(status).json({
      statusCode: status,
      timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
      path: request.url,
      message: exception.message,
    });
  }
}
```

2. exceptions-fitlers.module.ts

```
import { Module, Scope } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpExceptionFilter } from './http.exception-filter';
import { APP_FILTER } from '@nestjs/core';

@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_FILTER,
      scope: Scope.REQUEST,
      useClass: HttpExceptionFilter,
    },
  ],
})
export class ExceptionsFiltersModule {}
```

Service contains controller that uses this filter:

1. app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ExceptionsFiltersModule } from '@name/nodejs-lib/dist';

@Module({
  imports: [ExceptionsFiltersModule, ...],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

2. controller.ts

```
@Controller('app')
@UseFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter())
export class AppController{
  @Post('/check')
  @HttpCode(200)
  async check(@Body() dto: A): Promise<B> {
    throw new BadRequestException('Invalid data');
  }
}
```

3. main.ts

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './modules/app.module';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { DocumentationBuilder, HttpExceptionFilter } from '@name/nodejs-lib/dist';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });
  const config = app.get(ConfigService);

  app.useGlobalFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter());

  await app.listen(config.get<number>('HTTP_PORT'), () => {
    logger.log(`HTTP Server: http://${config.get('HTTP_HOST')}:${config.get('HTTP_PORT')}`);
  });
}

bootstrap().then();
```

Then I trying trigger this filter, I receive generic response:

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "message": "Invalid data",
  "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

If someone has opinion, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: UPD: When I changed the ```@Catch(HttpException)``` to ```@Catch()``` it worked

Comment: How are you making use of this external library? Is it a local link? Nx monorepo with a path alias? Installed package? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me.

It's because the HttpException instance you are using on your shared library is different from the version you are using on your main project (even if it has the same name and version).

Effectively, using **@Catch()** instead of **@Catch(HttpException)** solve the issue because it catch all Exceptions.

If you found any other solution, let me know.